# Powershell Updating a Format-Table instead of making a new one

Tags: powershell, formatting

When I call `Format-Table` in powershell, It will create a new table on the console.

```
Column 1     Column 2
---------------------
A           B

Column 1     Column 2
---------------------
New A           New B
```

What I want is for the table to be updated.. similar to how write-progress updates a progress bar instead of making a new progress bar on every call

like so

```
 Column 1     Column 2
---------------------
New A           New B
```

Comment: Why not just clear the console per update

Comment: I dont want to remove all the other output above my table

Comment: You can rewrite all output after clearing the host.

Answer (score 0):

```
$Position = $Host.UI.RawUI.Cursorposition; $Table1 | Format-Table
$Host.UI.RawUI.Cursorposition = $Position; $Table2 | Format-Table
```

*Note 1*: If table (1) overflows the bottom of the screen, the Y position will shift.
*Note 2*: This works for a standard PowerShell window, e.g. the PowerShell *ISE* has a different `$Host` ([`Get-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-host?view=powershell-5.1])) format.